# How to make dynamic router base in config nuxt.config.js and set backend url target

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt.config.js

Help me please, I need get data company based first path name company example ***http://localhost:3000/company_name/***,
also the company name must be dynamic.

I was currently thinking of performing the data query in the configuration of ***nuxt.config.js***

Or help me establish a good practice to do it

Comment: Please ellaborate your question better.

Comment: What do you have of code snippets? Do you already have an API providing this company data?

Comment: I currently have an api that receives the company identifier as a parameter, to return relevant information about the company, if the first path corresponds to the company, if it does not exist, it redirects to a custom screen